# Error loading datetime column to SQL Server table using informatica

Tags: sql-server, informatica

Facing issue while trying to load date time column to SQL Server table from through informatica.

I have an output port: `SYSDATE` which is directly loaded into a SQL Server table column (data type `datetime`).

Error message:

> Message: Database errors occurred:
>   FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC SQL Server Legacy Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
>   FnName: Execute -- 523 158

Comment: Error seems quite straight forward. What ever string you're passing, isn't able to be implicitly converted to a date/time data type. I *assume* Informatica has support for date/time datatypes though.

Comment: Could you please convert target data type to datetime2 and try? Sometime nanosecond can be an issue. Now regarding Larnu's comment, I dont think this is a string>datetime conversion issue. The o/p port OP mentioned is of type datetime.

Comment: What is the PORT datatype?

Comment: expression transformation port data type is date time.. when I changed SQL server field data type to varchar, it worked.. but with date time it is failing